# #include <mysql.h> in Eclipse for C++ doesn't work - how to configure it ?

Tags: c++, mysql, eclipse, include

Given the following :

```
// Include Header Files
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

// For MySQL Connection
#include <mysql.h>

using namespace std;

// Defining Constant Variables
#define SERVER "localhost"
#define USER "root"
#define PASSWORD "password"
#define DATABASE "test"

int main()
{
    MYSQL *connect;
    connect = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (!connect)
    {
        cout << "Mysql Initialization Failed";
        return 1;
    }

    connect = mysql_real_connect(connect, SERVER, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE, 0,NULL,0);

    if (connect)
    {
        cout << "Connection Succeeded\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Connection Failed\n";
    }

    MYSQL_RES *res_set;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

    // Replace MySQL query with your query

    mysql_query (connect,"show tables");

    unsigned int i=0;

    res_set=mysql_store_result(connect);

    unsigned int numrows = mysql_num_rows(res_set);

    cout << " Tables in " << DATABASE << " database " << endl;

    while (((row=mysql_fetch_row(res_set)) !=NULL))
    {
        cout << row[i] << endl;
    }

    mysql_close (connect);

    return 0;
}
```

The following include : `#include <mysql.h>` produces `Unresolved inclusion: <mysql.h>`  .
Any idea how resolve this ?

Comment: Somewhere in the project settings, you can add include paths. Add the path to where the `<mysql.h>` file is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to [configure](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/tasks/cdt_t_proj_paths.htm) the include path of Eclipse to let it find the file `mysql.h`.